# separar palabras ingresadas en un char

Tags: c

Estoy realizando uno cuantos ejercicios en los cuales tengo que comparar palabras de una cadena de caracteres ingresada por el usuario, en un ejercicio tengo que ver cuantas veces se repite una palabra en de todo la cadena que ingreso el usuario y en otro ejercicio tengo que ver si una palabra tiene `IE`, si lo tiene, tengo que imprimir esa palabra en especifico.

El problema aquí es que no tengo la menor idea de cómo separar las palabras de todo el `char` para luego poder trabajar con las palabras por separado.

¿Cómo puedo separar las palabras ingresadas, según lo que describo en mi pregunta?

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{//Programa para ver frecuencia de palabras
char cadena[60];
int i,j;//Controladores de los ciclos for
printf("Ingresa una oracion\n");
scanf("%[^\n]"&cadena);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amigo Cristian, por consenso en la comunidad, en las preguntas sobre ejercicios **hay que mostrar el código que ya tienes**. Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/57817/edit) tu pregunta para mostrarlo.

Comment: Creo que hay muchas maneras de hacer estos 2 ejercicios,pudiera ser  primero  hacer un array de char suficientemente largo, luego leer toda la linea, luego recorrer el array para ver cuantas palabras tiene, luego hacer un array dinamico  para almacenar todas las palabras y finalmente ir comparando una a una las palabras con todo el array aumentano contadores individuales. te insto a que en primer lugar hagas un código que lea la cadena, lo publiques en esta pregunta y así sera mas fácil enfocarse en el tema de contar las ocurrencias

Comment: ¿Algo de código que hayas realizado para ver el problema actual?

Comment: Hola Cristian, excelente por el código que muestras, creo que de allí lo que faltaría seria recorrer ese array con un ciclo `while(cadena[i] != '\n') ` luego muestras `printf("%c \n", cadena[i])`y cierras el ciclo con `i++`incrementando el indice.. ensaya esta solución y muestra el código ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para separar las palabras puedes usar [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) o iterar sobre la cadena buscando caracteres que no sean letras (espacios, comas, puntos, ...).

> en un ejercicio tengo que ver cuantas veces se repite una palabra en  cadena que ingreso el usuario

Si el ejercicio no es excesivamente puñetero mezclando letras, números y símbolos diversos (punto, coma, punto y coma, guiones, paréntesis, etc...) lo más sencillo sería despiezar la cadena de entrada con `strtok` y comparar cada subcadena con la palabra inicial:

```
const char* ptr = strtok(cadena," ,.");
while( ptr != 0 )
{
  if( strcmp(ptr,palabraABuscar) == 0 )
    printf("BINGO!!!\n");
  ptr = strtok(NULL," ,.");
}
```

> en otro ejercicio tengo que ver si una palabra tiene IE, si lo tiene, tengo que imprimir esa palabra en especifico

Puedes emplear la misma lógica pero sustituyendo [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) por una función que busque subcadenas, como [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/):

```
const char* cadena = "abcdefg";
if( strstr(cadena,"bc" ) != NULL )
  printf("subcadena bc encontrada\n");
else
  printf("subcadena bc NO encontrada\n");

if( strstr(cadena,"bb" ) != NULL )
  printf("subcadena bb encontrada\n");
else
  printf("subcadena bb NO encontrada\n");
```